# How do I Limit Div size?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my div stay around 70% to the left but my width is too big. **If I do `max-width: 500px` the div goes to the center.**

**In green you can see the size of the div**
[image]

How can I reduce the width of the div and keep the div in that position?
***Also I wanted to make the "$user" go the right of the image.***

CSS

```
.post {
width: 70%;
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="post">                    
                 <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>                
                 <img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo $image;?>" >
                 <div class="postRef" >
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php echo $likes;?> likes</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php echo $comments; ?> comments</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php echo $user; ?></button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="postBtns">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Keep it to one question per post. If you have another issue related to this one just make a new post, asking the specific question.

Comment: @Don sorry but I can only post every 90 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: auto` automatically gives half of the remaining space to the left and right margins thus centering it. If you want the div on the left side of the screen just remove the margin you're giving it.

**EDIT**

After reading in the comments it seems like what you want is a 2-column type system. In order to position the post in the way you want you should use a global container, and then position that and have posts take up a fraction of that space:

```
.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.post-container{
  float:left;
  width: 70%;
}
.other-container{
  width: 29%;
  float: right;
  background: pink;
}
.post {
  display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
background: lightblue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="post-container">

  <div class="post">                    
                 <h1>GIF</h1>                
                 <img src="" >
                 <div class="postRef" >
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">4 likes</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">5 comments</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">User</button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="postBtns">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
                 </div>
             </div>
  <div class="post">                    
                 <h1>GIF</h1>                
                 <img src="" >
                 <div class="postRef" >
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">4 likes</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">5 comments</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">User</button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="postBtns">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
                 </div>
             </div>
</div>

<div class="other-container">
Other stuff!!!!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>and others.
</div>
</div>
             </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1g57b5o3/2/

Comment: You need to clarify your question then. Try not to use references like "the div"  and refer to it by the class in the HTML.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to make the class post stay around 33% of the width. Like this site: https://9gag.com/   and make the width of the div post the like 500px (the width of the images)

Comment: You need to put your post into a container div which has a max-width, then let the post be left-aligned with a max width. I'll put an example in the original answer.

Comment: Ok. I can do it like this: ` margin: 0px 0px 0px 150px; max-width: 500px;` but it's not responsive. Once I make the windows smaller it stays the same size.

Comment: No problem. Just a bit of advice, when thinking of how to layout a page, you want to think from the outside in, not the inside out. Think about basic page layout in columns and containers then in which of those containers posts will go. I think that way you'll have a much easier time getting things laid out how you like.